# Is it possible to add/update metadata to a BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a data pipeline that is updating a set of BigQuery tables. What we want to do is to register in the table metadata, the date of the beginning of the update process and not the date of the last modification. Do you know if it is possible to add and update this kind of data to the table metadata ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of routes you can go here as you cannot override the native metadata like the last_modification time.

1. Use [labels](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adding-labels#bq) in BigQuery.  Provide a key value pair like `update_start`:`timestamp`
2. Similarly use [Data Catalog](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference) to register the value as a key value pair.